# XmlSlurper or StreamingMarkupBuilder Stripping Namespaces

Tags: groovy

I have an XSD whose root element contains two namespace declarations that aren't used in the subsequent schema definition, e.g., `xmlns:foo="urn:bar"` where foo isn't used.

When I use XmlSlurper and StreamingMarkupBuilder to read and write it out again unmodified:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder

public class NS {
   public static main(String[] args) {
      File xsdFile = new File("A.xsd")
      XmlSlurper slurper = new XmlSlurper()

      def xml = slurper.parse(xsdFile)
      def outputBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
      String xmlStr = outputBuilder.bind { mkp.yield xml }

      println xmlStr
   }
}
```

It is stripping off these namespace declarations.  How can I get these to read and write out the XML exactly as-is without any modification?

Answer (score 1):

Making `XmlSlurper` not namespace aware [via the constructor](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html#XmlSlurper%28boolean,%20boolean%29) seems to give you the result you need:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def xsd = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            |<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            |            xmlns:foo="http://www.example.com/foo">
            |   <xsd:simpleType name="Severity">
            |     <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            |       <xsd:enumeration value="pass"/>
            |       <xsd:enumeration value="fail"/>
            |       <xsd:enumeration value="error"/>
            |     </xsd:restriction>
            |   </xsd:simpleType>
            |</xsd:schema>'''.stripMargin()

def xml = new XmlSlurper( false, false ).parseText( xsd )
def outputBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
String xmlStr = XmlUtil.serialize( outputBuilder.bind { mkp.yield xml } )
println xmlStr
```